# MySQL Found_Rows() Returns Double the Correct Value

Tags: java, mysql

I have 3 records in my database (for testing purposes) and I am using SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS to return the row count in conjunction with LIMIT to gather paginated results.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM contacts WHERE contacts.organizationId = :organizationId LIMIT 0, 1
```

I am using Spring to do my database business login as so.

```
public List<Contact> findAll(int organizationId, int rowStart, int rowAmount, final boolean deep) {
    final HashMap<String, Object> namedParameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    namedParameters.put("organizationId", String.valueOf(organizationId));
    namedParameters.put("rowStart", rowStart);
    namedParameters.put("rowAmount", rowAmount);
    final NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager = new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
    TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager);

    List<Contact> contactList = transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallback<List<Contact>>() {

        @Override
        public List<Contact> doInTransaction(TransactionStatus status) {
            SqlRowSet result = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet(SQL_FIND_ALL_BY_ORGANIZATION_ID, namedParameters);
            int count = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForInt("SELECT FOUND_ROWS()", (HashMap<String, ?>) null);
            System.out.println(count);
            List<Contact> contactList = mapContact(result, deep);
            if(contactList.size() > 0) {
                return contactList;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }

    });
    return contactList;
}
```

No matter what I do, the count comes back as 6, when I only have 3 rows in the table. In fact, it is returning 6 regardless of how many rows are in the resultset. Why is the number doubling, what I am doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

I ended up using this:

```
int count = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForInt("SELECT Count(*) FROM contacts WHERE contacts.organizationId = :organizationId", namedParameters);
```

Basically the same as I was doing before but the SQL changed a little. I am now using count as opposed to SQL_CALC which I think results in two separate queries, but with Spring it seems to be the only way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a side effect of using `SqlRowSet`. Perhaps JDBC driver issues some queries internally to support it.

If you don't need specific features of `SqlRowSet` it would be better to use more traditional approaches. For example, it would be better to use `RowMapper<Contact>` to query for `List<Contact>`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of an old post, but since I came across it while researching and this didn't quite satisfy my needs, once I figured it all out, I wrote everything up here. https://www.contradodigital.com/2018/01/06/how-to-use-sql_calc_found_rows-and-found_rows-with-limit-and-offset-in-a-mysql-query-using-java-and-jdbc/

In essence, for the MySQL FOUND_ROWS() to work, you need to run FOUND_ROWS() within the same JDBC Connection as the first query. This will ensure the data returned is accurate.